# How does IHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(customClient) creates the async definition of an HttpClient?

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I've stumbled in a peculiar case where the named `HttpClient` that I want to build is run with an async function, like this:

```
  services.AddHttpClient("customClient", async (serviceProvider, httpClient) => {...});
```

And then when I try to recall it from an instance of `IHttpClientFactory` inside a service in which I want to use it, like this:

```
  //Constructor start
  this.httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("customClient");
  //Constructor end
```

I end up with a half-assed `HttpClient`, where the `BaseAddress` is set but the `DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` is missing despite both are set in same `AddHttpClient` async function(but the `Authorization` header is only set after awaiting 1 call).

So I was wondering, like in the question title: what happen when `CreateClient(name)` is called synchronously meanwhile the `HttpClient` setup is asynchronous?

Isn't there a mechanism that awaits this kind of definitions? From what I tried, it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I was wondering, like in the question title: what happen when CreateClient(name) is called synchronously meanwhile the HttpClient setup is asynchronous?

The setup isn't allowed to be asynchronous. If you look at [all the overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), none of them take an asynchronous delegate.

And if you think about it, that makes sense. Dependency injection in general has rejected asynchronous initialization because if they *allowed* it, then *every* dependency resolution would have to be `await`ed.

> Isn't there a mechanism that awaits this kind of definitions? From what I tried, it doesn't seem so.

Nope. The common patterns are:

- If this is a one-time initialization, then do it *before* setting up your DI, and use the resulting value in your DI setup.
- If this must be done after startup, then consider injecting an asynchronous HttpClient factory (no type like this is built-in; you'll have to use your own).
- If this needs to be done periodically (e.g., refreshing access tokens), then what you really want is a middleware (delegating handler) that (re-)acquires the token on demand.

Comment: Ok, I went to use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and I'm done :)

Comment: @Eugene that's a [dangerous game](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @ToddMenier I just use that call just once, then I use a cache to keep the data alive without ever calling every time that awaiting call. I think it's a good compromise. And when it come to refreshes of the auth header, there's another function call that deal with that without requiring to make again those calls inside the `AddHttpClient`.

Is it a good enough compromise?

Comment: Stephen is the real expert here, but I would say this: Is what you're doing technically "correct"? No. Practically speaking, if you're doing it once at startup, are you likely to ever actually see a deadlock occur? Probably not.